# Why is the integral of this term zero?

Tags: integration, physics, indefinite-integrals, electromagnetism

I came upon a problem in my physics textbook and had a question as to why term was equal to zero.

The equation and its integration :
\begin{align}
B &= u(H+I)
\\
dB&= u dH + udI
\\
\int HdB &= u \int HdH + u \int HdI
\end{align}
Next, my textbook says that since $\int HdH = 0$,
$$\int HdB = u \int HdI.$$

According to my rather basic understanding of Integration, since
$\int xdx = x^2/2$, shouldn’t the integration of $HdH$ give $H^2/2$?

Edit: For context,

1. $B = $ Magnetic Induction
2. $H = $ Intensity of Magnetic Field
3. $I = $ Intensity of Magnetisation
4. $ u = $ Magnetic Permeability

   Sorry if the answer is physics based instead of maths.

Comment: What is H? What is B? Give us some context! And use MathJax!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: I've done the MathJax for you this time, you can click on "edit" to see what I did so that you can copy it in the future.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinKhor ! Will do that for sure next time.

Comment: One possibility: if you are integrating from $H=-1$ to $H=+1$, then

$$ \int_{-1}^1 H dH = 1^2 - (-1)^2 = 0$$
this works for any region symmetric around the origin. I don't know if this is a physical scenario though